# CASE with AS query

Tags: mysql

I have about the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Product 
ORDER BY (SELECT CASE 
                     (SELECT MIN(date) FROM SomethingElse WHERE productId = Product.id) AS here 
                WHEN NULL 
                THEN 0 
                ELSE here
          ) DESC
```

However, AS in CASE doesn't work. I need a way to save the value in a variable and use it again.

Comment: AS do not save any values its only alias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you are trying to do `CASE when expression IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE expression END`?

In this case you can just use `COALESCE(expression, 0)`